# Is service necessary for grub

Tags: services

When I run, `sudo service --status-all | grep +` I can see all services, then for me is good remove all service and use most necessary only, then, what service I need not remove for don't modify grub configuration?, because another times when I remove services, one of they is necessary for grub, what is?